# Why variable inside function is being used outside the JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

I am new and learning JavaScript from Udemy

[This is my Script code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeOEW.png)

[This is my JavaScript Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o08c4.png)

[What answer should be according to Udemy Course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BML7.png)

Question is 
age variable is declared globally
so the second console.log should be 23 which is outside the function
what am i doing wrong ?
but the console.log is taking the variable from the function !

Comment: thats the way javascript works.

Comment: Please paste code in the question and use the formatting tools. Don't post images of code.

Comment: @DanielA.White  As per Udemy Course it should be 23 
so is that guy teaching me wrong !

Comment: `age = 65` changes the variable declared `var age = 23` which is in global scope. Try `var age = 65` inside of `foo` for a different result. Or try putting `var age = 23` *after* your definition of `foo`.

Comment: You will find a very complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/1978785

Comment: blocks in javascript doesn't define a new scope. that's why this is happening.

Comment: Thank You all ! Found the solution for my problem 
in udemy they declared a variable inside function " var age = 65 "  which didnt changed variable  var age = 23 . which i didnt do it in my code !

Comment: Yep, the details matter. :)